# What green background on answers amount in a list of questions (user profile) means?

Tags: discussion

What is the green background over number of answers in [list of questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8319/webmaohist?tab=questions) of a user profile [1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8319/webmaohist?tab=questions) supposed to tell?

Note that all questions have a correct answer marked

[image: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8319/webmaohist?tab=questions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers you are refering to are the ones that the one asking the question have marked as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

And as difference the green color indicates only that there are answers. Kind of to fragmented, because an answer without an upvote gives also green number color. Like [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/in-a-dvwp-my-multilookup-column-is-not-returning-ids-only-column-values), where the only answer has no votes, but [returns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=dvwp%20multilookup&submit=search) green number.

Comment: To clarify this person's statement, the green text denotes there's an answer there (see where it says # answers, when # is > 1).  The green background denotes that one of those answers was selected as the correct answer.